# Get cross object Picklist value for validation

Tags: custom-object, picklist

I Have 3 objects.

All with MD relationship

"Object 1"  Master of "Object 2" and "Object 2" Master of "Object 3".

Now, object 3 has one number field which needs to be checked against picklist field in object 1 for less than comparison. Any Suggestions.

Comment: How many values do you have in your picklist? I'm sure it would be numbers and a finite list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after an exact match, the below should work.

Validation rule: text(Object1.Picklist) != text(Object3.Field)

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1:**

If you have a finite no of picklist values in your object 1 and are easily manageable I would reccomend to use the [ISPICKVAL](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISPICKVAL) function.

```
 IF( 
    ISPICKVAL(Object2__r.Object1__r.PicklistField__c, '1') ,  NumberField__c > 1 , 
    IF( 
        ISPICKVAL(Object2__r.Object1__r.PicklistField__c, '2'), NumberField__c > 2,
        IF( 
            ISPICKVAL(Object2__r.Object1__r.PicklistField__c, '3'), NumberField__c > 3,
            FALSE
        )
    )
)
```

Similarly you can add on the ISPICKVAL up to the picklist you have.

I can help you better if you share more details on this validation in more precise details.

**OPTION 2:**

Use the Apex Trigger in Before Insert context and just perform the string to number conversion with Integer.valueOf function and add error.

Thank You.

Comment: Please mark it as solved if what I explained solves the problem else elaborate the problem for more help you need.